# How does direct sequence n-bit chipping code recover bit in the event of interference?

Tags: wireless, networking

Say for example my data stream was 1010.Using **4-bit chipping code**, with a random sequence of **0100101101011001**. The XOR'd data which the receiver receives is **1011101110101001**.
I understand that receiver, knowing the random sequence, has ***4 opportunities to recover a bit*** in case of interference. (eg. for first 4 received bits, 1=>1,0=>1,1=>1,1=>1 so we know original bit sent was 1)
But what if interference caused say 3 bits to flip?
 Eg. the first 4 bits received would be 0101. This would be decoded as 0=>0,1=>0,0=>0,1=>1.
How does the receiver know that the **first 3 results are wrong** but the final is correct?

(source:Computer networks: a systems approach chapter 2.6)

Comment: *Any* forward error correction has its limits.

Comment: What's the idea then? Is it perhaps a best of 4 kind of logic?

Comment: You could start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_code_keying) and work your way up to IEEE 802.11.